# Validação data-required em select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho este código que ele verifica se existe algum `input` com `data-required` que não foi preenchido, para informar para o usuário. Porém eu tenho 3 `selects` que não estão sendo verificados.

```
 $.each($('input[data-required="true"]'), function (e) {
        if (!this.value || this.value == '') {
            verificaform = 1;
            $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            var id = $($(this).parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
            $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
            $(this).focus();
            e.preventDefault(); // Vai prevenir o submit do formulário
            return false; // Vai parar a execução do .each()
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('border', '#CCCCCC 1px solid');
        }

        if ($('#ClienteNovo').valid()) {
            verificaform = 0;
        }
    });
```

Este é um deles

```
<label asp-for="CidadeEntrega" class="col-md-1 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
         <select asp-for="CidadeEntrega" asp-items="@Model.CidadeEntregaList" required id="cbmunicipioentrega" class="form-control uppercase"> <option disabled selected>Selecione o Município</option></select>
         <span asp-validation-for="CidadeEntrega" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Como posso fazer para eles serem validados, pois se não forem preenchidos ele deixa passar do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Tenta fazer o *selector* dessa forma `$('select[required]')`, ou seja, procurar por `select`s com o attr `required`, o seu *selector* esta procurando por `input`s com attr `data-required='true'`

Comment: @IcaroMartins é porque eu preciso procurar os `input` tb, como posso adaptar pros dois ?

Comment: você pode colocar uma `,` e ficar assim `$('input[data-required="true"],select[required]')`

Comment: @IcaroMartins quando faço dessa forma `$.each($('input[data-required="true"]','select[required]'), function (e) {` não funciona, ele não funciona nem para os `input`

Comment: O selector tem que estar desta forma  `selector = 'input[data-required="true"], select[required]'`, note que não é 2 selectors. `$( selector ).each( function(){ } );` - [jQuery - Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: @IcaroMartins era isso mesmo, eu estava fazendo da forma errada, por isso não dava certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso você precisa combinar os selectors do jQuery utilizando `,` entre eles veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
/// ; Selector para retornar os inputs com attr data-require=true
$('input[data-required="true"]') 

/// ; Selector para retornar os selects com attr required
$('select[required]')


/// ; Para retornar os inputs com attr data-required=true &&
/// ; Para retornar os selects com attr required
$( 'input[data-required="true"], select[required]' )
//   ↑                         ↑   ↑
//   Selector1                 |   |
//                     separador   |
//                                 Selector2

/// var selector = 'input[data-required="true"], select[required]';
/// $( selector );
```

[jQuery - Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)